# adding a column if record exists in two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables.  One is a list of all categories. The other is a list of categories a thing might belong to. A thing can belong to more than one category (it might have more than one record in table two)

So, I have

table:

```
categories 
1,   horror
2,   romance
3,   post modern
4,   Canadian
5,    English

...
2340
```

Then another table, thingsToCategories, with two columns (thingID, categoryID)

```
thingID   categoryID
6323-01    1
6323-01    4
6323-01    5
1342-01    2
1342-01    4
```

Given a thingID, I need a list of all categories (as in select * from table A), with an indication of whether that thing ID exists in table B

So, given thingID of 6323-01, I need a list like this:

```
1,   horror    selected
2,   romance
3,   post modern
4,   Canadian   selected
5,    English   selected
```

My SQL skills are rusty and bad enough I'm not even sure what sort of join to use.  Can anyone give any pointers?

(I inherited this database, fwiw)

Comment: You can work this using a view instead of creating a table

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM categories
INNER JOIN thingsToCategories ON categories.CategoryID = thingsToCategories.CategoryID
WHERE thingsToCategories.thingID ='6323-01'
```

INNER JOIN will ensure a selection based on records that match in both tables.

Comment: Otherwise if you use a `LEFT JOIN` and select on categories, if there isn't a record in thingsToCategories, it will show a `NULL`

Comment: That gives me back the entire Categories table * the number of times the item appears in table B

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what you want your final result to be. Do you just want categories 1,4,5?

Comment: I do seem to be struggling to convey this :).  I want all of the categories, but with three of them (1, 4, and 5) indicating that they exist in table B.

Comment: The question I am asking the database, in english, is "please give me a complete list of categories_ids, and for this thingID, indicate which ones are selected"

Comment: You want to use an `INNER JOIN` then. Any IDs that don't match between the tables won't be selected. So if you join `Categories.CategoryID` on `ThingsToCategories.CategoryID` you should just get 1,4,5 for that single thing ID

Comment: in code, its something like this:
`code`
allCategories = get_all_categories()
selectedCategories = get_categories_for_this_Thing('6323-01')

for each (category in allCategories)
{
    if (category is in selectedCategories)
    {
         category.selected = YES;
    }
}
`code`
But doing that is really, really slow, so I'm hoping to move it to the database instead of doing it in code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17946/discussion-between-dgarbacz-and-justin)